# Code Doesn't Execute?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
Array.class_eval do
    def abs_sort
        new_array = self
        self.each do |x|
            new_array.push(x.abs)
        end
        return new_array.sort
    end
end
```

When I try to run the code:

```
[1, 4, -2].abs_sort
```

Nothing happens, it just shows a blank screen. Why?

Comment: You could implement that as `def abs_sort; map(&:abs).sort; end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `new_array` to an actual new array, not `self`:

```
new_array = []
```

What's happening is that since `new_array` is `self`, you're adding items to the end of the array *as you iterate over it*, which means that the iteration never ends since you always have more items, and your method infinitely loops.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake when initializing the `new_array`. In any case, here's a more concise solution:

```
Array.class_eval do
  def abs_sort
    map(&:abs).sort
  end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: @muistooshort it sorts by the absolute value, doesn't it?

Comment: But it doesn't `abs` the whole array along the way. You want `map(&:abs).sort`.